# Setup and configuration of Intel RST on Asus motherboard

Tags: raid, intel-core-i5, hardware-raid, intel-rst

On boot there is no Intel RST screen that allows me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

However, the SATA mode has been set to Intel RST and ROM Messages are enabled.
The Intel RST drivers are installed and Windows 10 64 bit was installed after enabling IRST in the BIOS.

What else is needed to configure RST with my three HDDs?

Components:

> Asus ROG STRIX B360-G Motherboard
>   Intel Core I5-8400 CPU
>   RipJaws 2x8gb 2133mHz RAM
>   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GPU
>   3 each 1TB 7.2k RPM HDD

Comment: Verify you have plugged the drive into the correct SATA port.

Comment: Which of the three? The motherboard has six SATA ports of which the first 4 are occupied as follows:
1: 1TB drive
2: CD/DVD RW
3: 1TB drive
4: 1TB drive

Comment: Provide all relevant information in the body of your question.  As to which one, that requires reading the manual, and determining which ports belong to which controller.  You likely have two different SATA controllers from two different manufacturers.  *I would imagine only the Intel one would support Intel RST.*

Comment: The only time Intel RST is mentioned in the manual is on how to enable it, which I have already done.

Comment: The manual indicates that M2_2 supports IRST.  The manual does not indicate any other SATA port supports it. I assume you have the current, `Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver software`, installed?

Comment: So does that mean I need to get myself an M.2 SATA controller in order to be able to raid using IRST?

Comment: M2_2 is PCI-E M.2;  Verify if the current software is installed.  DId you enable IRST after the OS was installed?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did. Would that be a problem?

Comment: But I reinstalled Windows afterwards since it corrupted it.

Comment: As I said all relevant information should be contained in the question, all this information in comments, are going to be lost if/when they are deleted.  I still don't know if you have the IRST drivers installed and the IRST software installed.

Comment: I do, both the drivers and the GUI are installed.

Comment: Please provide enough information in the body of your question so it can be answered.

Comment: @PlanetTeamSpeak Please click on `edit` at left above, and add the updated facts we've asked for into the original post, then delete the comments they came from by clicking on the white-x-in-grey-circle after each comment. Many comments make reading hard :)  An M.2 drive is not required for RST (though an Optane drive in the M.2_2 slot sure will speed up the RAID). You must, after changing from AHCI to RST, add ea. HDD to an array. Strongly suggest NOT mixing SSDs & HDDs in the same RAID array! Suggest you plug the optical drive into a high numbered SATA port, like 05; HDDs in SATA 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: @K7AAZ after removing connecting the three drives to SATA 1, 2 and 3 and the DVD RW to SATA 6, and then changing the control mode from AHCI to IRST, there still seems to not be an Intel RST screen allowing me to create a raid. Also I do not have any SSDs, just 2 1tb WD Blue drives and a 1tb Seagate drive all of 7.2k rpm.